# Duplicate data, XmlHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Help, please.
I post
data `xmlhttprequest` to ASP.
Why are my contents duplicated?
If I do not write `document.getElementById('qz').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;` then nothing is displayed.

```
<body><div id="container"><button id="the-button" >Click me</button>
<form id="Form1" runat = "server">
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" 
    onclick="Button1_Click2" />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
<% string rd = Request["x"]; string rd1 = Request["y"];Response.Write("res"+rd+" "+rd1);%>
    </form> </div> <div id="qz"></div></body>



<script type="text/javascript">
   function get_var() {
        var x = "12";
        var y = "14"
        var params = 'x=' + encodeURIComponent(x) + '&y=' + encodeURIComponent(y);
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "pr_peremennya.aspx", true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                document.getElementById('qz').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        };

        xmlhttp.send(params);
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        document.getElementById("the-button").addEventListener("click", get_var);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: <body><div id="container"><button id="the-button" >Click me</button>
    <form id="Form1" runat = "server">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" 
        onclick="Button1_Click2" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
   <% string rd = Request["x"]; string rd1 = Request["y"];Response.Write("res"+rd+" "+rd1);%>
        </form> </div> <div id="qz"></div></body>

Comment: Please [edit] the question with the new information.

Comment: We need more clues : What is "qz" HTML element? We also need to see "pr_peremennya.aspx". How is data returned? Maybe the data is coming duplicated from the source.

Comment: @ Jose Manuel Abarca Rodríguez `<body>
   <div id="container">
   <button id="the-button" >Click me</button>
    <form id="Form1" runat = "server">
   <%
  string rd = Request["x"];
  string rd1 = Request["y"];
  Response.Write(rd+" "+rd1);
 
%>
        </form>
   </div>
     <div id="qz"></div>
</body>`